# Curious function problem (EDIT: Not so curious, but didn`t see it at the time of writing)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, irrational-numbers

This one is directly from my head and although it could be something trivial I do not see the way to attack it but the problem looks interesting and I want to share it with you, here it is:

Let us define function $f$ as $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{x}$.

Now, I wonder is there an easy way (or any way?) to prove (or disprove)  that for every interval $[x_1,x_2]\subset \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $x_1\neq x_2$ there exist irrational number $x_0\in [x_1,x_2]\setminus \{\displaystyle\frac{a\pi}{b}|\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb Q\}$, such that $f(x_0)$ is rational number, in other words, that every interval $[x_1,x_2]\subset \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ contains at least one irrational number $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is rational and $x_0$ is not rational multiple of $\pi$.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Read what you are writing and think a bit before asking.

Comment: @fedja I see now, I really do not know why I did not see it at the moment of writing. So trivial. Trivializingly trivial.

Comment: @fedja that sounds a bit angry... :( people sometimes do ask questions which have trivial answers, why should _all_ questions sound like problems from scientific seminars? People shoudn't be afraid of asking (and your comment isn't encouraging), no matter how trivial the question is, if they're really trying to do something. Sometimes you just can't notice something _really_ **trivial** (i know it from my own experience), and need someone's hint, there's nothing bad in it... IMHO. And i'm sorry if this comment is a kind of off topic...

Comment: @Alex No anger, irritation, offense, etc. was implied. Those were just the best ideas I could offer to the OP. Do you disagree that they would help him in this case and in the future?

Comment: @fedja Yes, in some cases discouraging comments can cause damage. Honestly, i've been in situations like this one, that's the reason i'm writing. Well, your comment sounded a kind of, say, discouraging. Perhaps i'm exaggerating the whole thing, but that comes only from my own experience. I'm just saying, sometimes you would not notice the most-most-most trivial thing in the whole world unless someone shows you the answer. We all need communication. Did the OP ask the question connected with his homework? No, it seems. They just asked, no cheating, or something like that, it seems to me...

Comment: @Alex OK, I'll be somewhat more careful. However, if you look at what the OP wrote himself in the post and *just read it slowly*, it contains the full answer. It is not a case when you don't see a thing that is not present, but one when you have done everything and just didn't spend a few minutes to reflect on what you did. I know a few mathematicians who would benefit enormously from slow reading of their own papers. My advice is real, not rhetoric in any way. Wording is another issue and I admit that I'm prone to cutting corners... I sincerely apologize for any damage but the message stays.

Comment: @fedja :) well, sentences 4 and 5 of your last comment sound a lot better, and i think that if you'd added them to your very first comment on this question, its meaning would've been much clearer! :)

Comment: @Alex White i even thought of deleting myself from this site because of this question but i think i will stay for some time because i really have some questions for which i cannot at the moment find an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Amateur i think that if you have questions, then you sould ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x_0)$ is rational if and only if $x_0$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. Note that $x=\frac1{f(x)}\cdot \pi$.

Comment: This is soooooooo trivial, I feel so embarrassed, I do not know why it wasn`t trivial to me in the moment when I was writing it. Thank you!